# Lazy Initializtion of C# property behaviour different during debugging

Tags: c#, visual-studio, lazy-evaluation

I have different behavior when i am trying to lazy initialize some data -while debugging and while running without debugging. While debugging this code, the property seems to be getting evaluated even before it is called! When run without debugging this doesn't take place(race condition of some sort?).

I have breakpoints on lines B2 and C2.
To be clear: I never expect to see the following line get printed, but I see it while debugging.. 
2: Checking hasvalue: True, 10/2/2016 10:10:56 PM

Am I doing something wrong with respect to using public properties or is this not the correct way to do lazy initialization?

```
namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    using System;

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("A2. Time is : {0}", DateTime.Now);
            var testNullablebool = new TestNullableBool();
            Console.WriteLine("B2. Time is : {0}", DateTime.Now); <BreakPoint here>
            Console.WriteLine("C2. Time is : {0}", DateTime.Now); <BreakPoint>
            Console.WriteLine("Answer 2: {0}, {1}", testNullablebool.IsFoundAnswer, DateTime.Now);
        }
    }

    public class TestNullableBool
    {
        private bool? isFound;

        public bool IsFoundAnswer
        {
            get
            {
                Console.WriteLine("2: Checking hasvalue: {0}, {1}", isFound.HasValue, DateTime.Now);
                if (!isFound.HasValue)
                {
                    if (DateTime.Now < DateTime.UtcNow)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("2: This is true, {0}", DateTime.Now);
                        isFound = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("2: This is false, {0}", DateTime.Now);
                        isFound = false;
                    }
                }
                return isFound.Value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output without debugging(no breakpoints!!):

```
A2. Time is : 10/2/2016 10:11:54 PM
B2. Time is : 10/2/2016 10:11:54 PM
C2. Time is : 10/2/2016 10:11:54 PM
2: Checking hasvalue: False, 10/2/2016 10:11:54 PM
2: This is true, 10/2/2016 10:11:54 PM
Answer 2: True, 10/2/2016 10:11:54 PM
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Output with breakpoint and single stepping:

```
A2. Time is : 10/2/2016 10:10:23 PM
B2. Time is : 10/2/2016 10:10:45 PM
C2. Time is : 10/2/2016 10:10:51 PM
2: Checking hasvalue: False, 10/2/2016 10:10:51 PM
2: This is true, 10/2/2016 10:10:51 PM
2: Checking hasvalue: True, 10/2/2016 10:10:56 PM
2: Checking hasvalue: True, 10/2/2016 10:10:58 PM
Answer 2: True, 10/2/2016 10:10:59 PM
2: Checking hasvalue: True, 10/2/2016 10:10:59 PM
```

Comment: The debugger assumes Getters are side-effect free, and thus if you have it in your watch list, it will evaluate it.

Comment: Or just mouse over the field :)

Comment: @Cine, yes. you are right. the debugger seems to be evaluating it. Just checking the value in locals is setting the value..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting comment above as answer - so that I can close this question.

The debugger assumes Getters are side-effect free, and thus if you have it in your watch list, it will evaluate it. – @Cine